# A rocket powered by Francium(element 87)?

Tags: spaceships, element

Francium is the most reactive of all alkali metals, in theory. It is so rare because its half-life is so short. But, using the Theory of Relativity, if you speed up the Francium in a particle accelerator, then time dilation makes it last longer, meaning it can be stored in a "light-speed limbo", if you will. Mixing it with water, when you need it, would create an explosion could be used to generate thrust. But are there any other ways of storing these particles for extended periods of time without using ridiculous amounts of electromagnets, and also be able to fit it on an interstellar spaceship?

Comment: if you have a particle accelerator powerful enough to speed up meaningful amounts of francium to significant fractions of C, you _don't need_ francium as rocket fuel. just use the accelerator with a non-decaying material as reaction mass to directly propel your spaceship

Comment: You can't keep something in storage and have it moving at the same time. Your francium would only experience the delayed time *while* it's moving super fast.

Comment: Upvote because the idea of prolonging the lives of elements by storing them in light speed limbo is pretty slick.  You can do better than Francium.  How about muonium?

Answer (score 10):

There's two problems here: First, Francium wouldn't make a very good rocket fuel; and second, life-extending it is counterproductive.

Francium is expected to be less electronegative (more reactive) than caesium, by about 10%. However, it's also much heavier than caesium, by about 67%. So the energy available per gram of fuel is much lower than caesium.

That said, you don't hear about caesium rockets very much. And that's because caesium, although more reactive than lithium (more energy per atom), is MUCH heavier (less energy per gram) -- by about 1900%.

And, that said... you don't hear about lithium/water rockets either. If you wanted to do an alkali rocket, lithium is by far your best choice -- but it's not nearly as good a fuel as traditional rocket fuel, but any metric.

Then, let's talk about relativistic life extension of Francium. The half life of Francium is around 22 minutes. Lets say you want to be able to store it for a decade (interstellar mission), and keep 90% of it usable. You need a half life around 65 years, or pretty close to 1500000x more than normal. To get this relativistically, you need to accelerate your francium to around 99.99999999998% the speed of light. Accelerating one gram of fuel to this speed takes about 142 million *million* ***million*** joules of energy. For one gram. The chemical energy in francium compared to, say, xeon is just a rounding error on this scale. If you have the energy to make francium relativistic (ignoring how to contain it), you don't care about the chemical energy it contains.

Oh, and that one gram of francium, moving that fast, now weighs around 1600000 grams...

Comment: (I think the math above is correct, but it's quite possible I lost an order of magnitude or two somewhere... these are big numbers!)

Answer (score 4):

The chemical energy density of francium is much smaller than the energy density of lighter alkali metals, especially lithium, so the idea does not make sense from the start. Just use lithium, it is stable, and react it with oxygen rather than water, that produces more energy!

The decay of francium and all its daughter nuclides itself would be a decent source of energy. It would give you around 25 MeV of energy from alpha decay (not counting beta and gamma emissions which would add a few MeV). That should amount to 12 Petajoule or so per ton of francium, millions of times more than you would get by reacting the francium with oxygen (let alone water!).

So if you could use francium as energy source you could exploit its radioactive decay directly, not its chemical energy.  However, one of its daughter isotopes, radium-223 has a half-life of 11 days, so the energy would not be released instantaneously.

As others have pointed out, storing francium at relativistic speed in an accelerator would require an insane amount of energy and is therefore not feasible.

Radioactive isotopes can also be made stable under high pressure, the kind of pressure you get in the crust of a neutron star where all kinds of exotic nuclei are predicted to exist. Needless to say there is no conceivable technology to achieve such pressures.

Both our francium storing methods, the relativistic cyclotron and the relativistic pressure chamber, would actually store a huge amount of energy by themselves, the first in the form of kinetic energy, the other in the form of thermal energy (as latent heat). That energy is many trillions of times more than your francium or any other radioisotope can provide by its decay and quintillions of times more than you get by chemical reactions. So if you could construct any of those things you could use any matter as "fuel", it would make no difference if it can react with water or not.

There is a third method to stabilize radioactive nuclei, but it only works with a certain type of radioisotoes, those radioisotopes that exclusively decay by electron capture (epsilon decay). You would have to completely ionize them, that is rid them of all their electrons, because without electrons there is nothing to capture and the nuclei would be stable!

They would have to be stored in a strong magnetic field to remain ionized. The best candidate would be beryllium-7, which could be produced for example as a by-product of lithium fusion and since it only contains 4 electrons it is relatively easy to ionize. The decay energy stored in beryllium-7 is hundreds of times more than the energy you need to ionize it. Half-life of Be-7 is 53 days.

However, epsilon decay only produces gamma rays, electromagnetic waves of very low wave lenght. It would be very difficult to convert this type of radiation into useful energy.

Answer (score 3):

With a half life of only 22 minutes for it most stable isotope, you would have a lot of trouble getting enough [Francium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Francium) and storing it for any purpose, as evidenced by the following quotes:

> Bulk francium has never been seen
>
> Francium is one of the most unstable of the naturally occurring elements
>
> Francium's melting point was estimated to be around 8.0 °C

I'd advise considering another fuel source.

Comment: OP's question _explicitly_ assumes some handwavium method to arbitrarily extend the half-life.